# Real time analytic using Apache Spark

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-spark, bigdata, cql3

I am using Apache Spark to analyse the data from Cassandra and will insert the data back into Cassandra by designing new tables in Cassandra as per our queries. I want to know that whether it is possible for spark to analyze in real time? If yes then how? I have read so many tutorials regarding this, but found nothing.

I want to perform the analysis and insert into Cassandra whenever a data comes into my table instantaneously.

Comment: What do you mean by real time? Like Spark Streaming?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Apache Storm](https://storm.apache.org/).

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking

Comment: Spark Streaming is generally used for data which is updating in real time and then act upon it. However, your question does not make clear what exactly you want to do, so a bit more information about it might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with Spark Streaming, you should take a look at the demos and documentation which comes packaged with the Spark Cassandra Connector.

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector

This includes support for streaming, as well as support for creating new tables on the fly.

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/8_streaming.md

> Spark Streaming extends the core API to allow high-throughput,
>   fault-tolerant stream processing of live data streams. Data can be
>   ingested from many sources such as Akka, Kafka, Flume, Twitter,
>   ZeroMQ, TCP sockets, etc. Results can be stored in Cassandra.

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/5_saving.md#saving-rdds-as-new-tables

> Use saveAsCassandraTable method to automatically create a new table
>   with given name and save the RDD into it. The keyspace you're saving
>   to must exist. The following code will create a new table words_new in
>   keyspace test with columns word and count, where word becomes a
>   primary key:
>
> case class WordCount(word: String, count: Long) val collection =
>   sc.parallelize(Seq(WordCount("dog", 50), WordCount("cow", 60)))
>   collection.saveAsCassandraTable("test", "words_new",
>   SomeColumns("word", "count"))

Comment: Hi, thank u for the post. Now am dealing with the same process using connector and streaming. But its  causing the server running very slow. How can i reduce this ? This is the reason why i went to look for other techniques in spark for real time analytics.